# Problem with pagination using Sieve package

Tags: c#, asp.net, pagination, asp.net-core-webapi, sieve.net

I am building small WebApi (with CQRS and MediatR) as my portfolio to my first job in IT and I am facing some problem with using [Sieve.net](https://github.com/Biarity/Sieve)  to filter, sort and paginate the result. For now I have problem with pagination.

I want to receive data like this:

```json
{
    "currentPage": 1,
    "pageSize": 5,
    "pageCount": 1,
    "rowCount ": 5,
    "data": [
      {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "name",
          "description": "description,
       }
     ]
}
```

I have created a base class:

```cs
public abstract class PagedRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> : IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>
       where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    public abstract Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

PagedResponseExtension:

```cs
public static class PagedResponseExtension
{
    public static async Task<PagedResponse<TResponse>> ToPagedAsync<TEntity, TResponse>
           (this IQueryable<TEntity> query, IMapper mapper, ISieveProcessor sieve, SieveModel model = null,
           CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) where TResponse : ResponseBase<TResponse>
    {
        var page = model?.Page ?? 1;
        var pageSize = model?.PageSize ?? 50;

        if (model != null)
            query = sieve.Apply(model, query, applyPagination: false);

        var rowCount = await query.CountAsync(cancellationToken);
        var pageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)rowCount / pageSize);

        var skip = (page - 1) * pageSize;
        var pagedQuery = query.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize);

        var response = new PagedResponse<TResponse>
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                PageSize = pageSize,
                PageCount = pageCount,
                RowCount = rowCount
            };

        response.Results = await pagedQuery.ProjectTo<TResponse>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                                           .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

        return response;
    }
}
```

PagedResponse:

```cs
public class PagedResponse<TResponse> where TResponse : class
{
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
    public long RowCount { get; set; }

    public IList<TResponse> Results { get; set; } = new List<TResponse>();

    public ErrorModel Error { get; internal set; }
}
```

GetProductsQuery:

```cs
public class GetProductsQuery : QueryBaseWithSieve<List<Product>>
{
    public SieveModel SieveModel { get; init; }

    public async override Task<List<Product>> Execute(FlowerShopStorageContext context, ISieveProcessor sieveProcessor)
    {
        var query = sieveProcessor.Apply(SieveModel, context.Products.AsNoTracking());
            
        return await query.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

This is my current `QueryHandler`:

```cs
public class GetProductsHandler : IRequestHandler<GetProductsRequest, GetProductsResponse>
{
    private readonly IMapper mapper;
    private readonly IQueryExecutor queryExecutor;

    public GetProductsHandler(IMapper mapper, IQueryExecutor queryExecutor)
    {
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.queryExecutor = queryExecutor;
    }

    public async Task<GetProductsResponse> Handle(GetProductsRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var query = new GetProductsQuery()
            {
                SieveModel = request.SieveModel
            };

        var products = await this.queryExecutor.ExecuteWithSieve(query);

        if (products == null)
        {
            return new GetProductsResponse()
                {
                    Error = new ErrorModel(ErrorType.NotFound)
                };
        }

        var mappedProducts = this.mapper.Map<List<Domain.Models.ProductDTO>>(products);

        var response = new GetProductsResponse()
            {
                Data = mappedProducts
            };

        return response;
    }
}
```

This is how I try to solve it:

```cs
public class GetProductsHandler : PagedRequestHandler<GetProductsRequest, PagedResponse<GetProductsResponse>>
{
    private readonly IMapper mapper;
    private readonly IQueryExecutor queryExecutor;
    private readonly SieveProcessor sieveProcessor;

    public GetProductsHandler(IMapper mapper, IQueryExecutor queryExecutor, SieveProcessor sieveProcessor)
    {
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.queryExecutor = queryExecutor;
        this.sieveProcessor = sieveProcessor;
    }

    public override async Task<PagedResponse<GetProductsResponse>> Handle(GetProductsRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var query = new GetProductsQuery()
            {
                SieveModel = request.SieveModel
            };

        var products = await this.queryExecutor.ExecuteWithSieve(query);

        if (products == null)
        {
            return new PagedResponse<GetProductsResponse>()
                {
                    Error = new ErrorModel(ErrorType.NotFound)
                };
        }

        products.AsQueryable();
        // var mappedProducts = this.mapper.Map<List<Domain.Models.ProductDTO>>(products);
            
        var response = new PagedResponse<GetProductsResponse>()
            {
                //Results = products
                // Data = mappedProducts
                //Results = (IList<GetProductsResponse>)products  //mappedProducts   
                //products.ToList()
            };

    // Error    CS1929  'PagedResponse<GetProductsResponse>' does not contain a definition for 'ToPagedAsync' and the best extension method overload 
    // 'PagedResponseExtension.ToPagedAsync<GetProductsRequest, GetProductsResponse>(IQueryable<GetProductsRequest>, IMapper, ISieveProcessor, SieveModel, CancellationToken)' 
    // requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<GetProductsRequest>' Shop.ApplicationServices    C:\...\Shop.ApplicationServices\API\Handlers\Product\GetProductsHandler.cs
         
        return await response.ToPagedAsync<GetProductsRequest, GetProductsResponse>(query, mapper, sieveProcessor, request.SieveModel);  

        //return response.ToPagedAsync<GetProductsRequest, GetProductsResponse>();         
    }
}
```

Also in `ProductsController` I get this issue:

> The type 'Shop.ApplicationServices.API.Domain.Product.GetProductsRequest' cannot be used as type parameter 'TRequest' in the generic type or method
> 'ApiControllerBase.HandleRequest<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from
> 'Shop.ApplicationServices.API.Domain.Product.GetProductsRequest' to 'MediatR.IRequest<Shop.ApplicationServices.API.Domain.Product.GetProductsResponse>'. Shop   C:...\Shop\Controllers\ProductsController.cs

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllProducts([FromQuery] SieveModel sieveModel)
{            
    GetProductsRequest request = new GetProductsRequest { SieveModel = sieveModel };

    return await this.HandleRequest<GetProductsRequest, GetProductsResponse>(request);
}
```

Am I trying to solve whole this issue correctly?

Thank you in advance!

Best regards,
Lukas

Answer (score 0):

I answear my own question to show my changes in code (but now getting an exception):

```cs
public abstract class PagedRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> : IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>
        where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
   public abstract Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

PagedResponseExtension:

```cs
public static class PagedResponseExtension
{
    public static async Task<PagedResponse<TEntity>> ToPagedAsync<TResponse, TEntity> (this IQueryable<TEntity> query, IMapper mapper, ISieveProcessor sieve, SieveModel model = null,
   CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) where TResponse : class        
    {
        var page = model?.Page ?? 1;
        var pageSize = model?.PageSize ?? 50;

        if (model != null)
               query = sieve.Apply(model, query, applyPagination: false);

        var rowCount = await query.CountAsync(cancellationToken);
        var pageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)rowCount / pageSize);

        var skip = (page - 1) * pageSize;
        var pagedQuery = query.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize);

        var response = new PagedResponse<TEntity>
        {
            CurrentPage = page,
            PageSize = pageSize,
            PageCount = pageCount,
            RowCount = rowCount               
        };

        response.Results = await pagedQuery.ProjectTo<TEntity>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);;

        return response;
    }
}
```

PagedResponse:

```cs
public class PagedResponse<TResponse> where TResponse : class
{
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
    public long RowCount { get; set; }

    // public IList<TResponse> Results { get; set; } = new List<TResponse>();
    public List<TResponse> Results { get; set; } = new();
}
```

GetProductsQuery:

```cs
public class GetProductsQuery : QueryBaseWithSieve<IQueryable<Entities.Product>>
//public class GetProductsQuery : QueryBaseWithSieve<List<Product>>
{
    public SieveModel SieveModel { get; init; }

    public async override Task<IQueryable<Entities.Product>> Execute(FlowerShopStorageContext context, ISieveProcessor sieveProcessor)
    // public async override Task<List<Product>> Execute(FlowerShopStorageContext context, ISieveProcessor sieveProcessor)
    {
        var query = sieveProcessor.Apply(SieveModel, context.Products.AsNoTracking());
         
        return await Task.FromResult(query);   
        // return await query.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

This is how I solved it:

```cs
//public class GetProductsHandler : IRequestHandler<GetProductsRequest, GetProductsResponse>
public class GetProductsHandler : PagedRequestHandler<GetProductsRequest, GetProductsResponse>
{
    private readonly IMapper mapper;
    private readonly IQueryExecutor queryExecutor;
    // Here in place of implementation I need to use interface
    // private readonly SieveProcessor sieveProcessor;
    private readonly ISieveProcessor sieveProcessor;
       
    public GetProductsHandler(IMapper mapper, IQueryExecutor queryExecutor, ISieveProcessor sieveProcessor)
    {
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.queryExecutor = queryExecutor;
        this.sieveProcessor = sieveProcessor;
    }
    public override async Task<GetProductsResponse> Handle(GetProductsRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    //public override async Task<PagedResponse<GetProductsResponse>> Handle(GetProductsRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var query = new GetProductsQuery()
        {
            SieveModel = request.SieveModel
        };

        var products = await this.queryExecutor.ExecuteWithSieve(query);
        if (products is null)
        {
            return new GetProductsResponse()
            {
                Error = new ErrorModel(ErrorType.NotFound)
            };
        }

        var mappedProducts = this.mapper.Map<IQueryable<ProductDTO>>(products);

        var results = await mappedProducts.ToPagedAsync<GetProductsResponse, ProductDTO>(mapper, sieveProcessor);
        //var results  = await mappedProducts.ToPagedAsync<ProductDTO, GetProductsResponse>(mapper, sieveProcessor);

        var response = new GetProductsResponse() { Data = results };

        return response;
    }
}
```

I got no issues now but cannot build a project. But get some exceptions, depends on registration in Startup.cs:

- System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[FlowerShop.ApplicationServices.API.Domain.Product.GetProductsRequest,FlowerShop.ApplicationServices.API.Domain.Product.GetProductsResponse] Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: FlowerShop.ApplicationServices.API.Handlers.Product.GetProductsHandler': Unable to resolve service for type 'Sieve.Services.SieveProcessor' while attempting to activate 'FlowerShop.ApplicationServices.API.Handlers.Product.GetProductsHandler'.)'
- InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Sieve.Services.SieveProcessor' while attempting to activate 'FlowerShop.ApplicationServices.API.Handlers.Product.GetProductsHandler'.

or:

- System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot instantiate implementation type 'FlowerShop.ApplicationServices.API.Handlers.PagedRequestHandler`2[FlowerShop.ApplicationServices.API.Domain.Product.GetProductsRequest,FlowerShop.ApplicationServices.API.Domain.Product.GetProductsResponse]' for service type 'MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[FlowerShop.ApplicationServices.API.Domain.Product.GetProductsRequest,FlowerShop.ApplicationServices.API.Domain.Product.GetProductsResponse]'.'

This is my Startup.cs

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{  
    // Here I changend the way of registration
    // services.AddScoped<ISieveProcessor, ApplicationSieveProcessor>();
    services.AddScoped<ISieveProcessor, SieveProcessor>();
}
```

**Edit:**
I solved this issue but got another one with mapping but I will write about this in the new question.